# How to set a supported mode for an external display?

Tags: java, android

I am currently writing an android app that displays information on an external display that is connected to my device via USB-C.

Everything works as intended, besides the display using the wrong resolution. When I ask the Display object for its supported modes it lists a couple of supported resolutions.

I fail to find a way to enforce a different mode on the external display, though!

```
Display.Mode[] modes = mExternalDisplay.getSupportedModes();
for (int i = 0; i < modes.length; i++) {
    Log.e(TAG, modes[i].toString());
}
```

Can any one help?